# Do Facebook apps have to ask for user permissions at the start?

Tags: facebook, permissions

Whenever I first click on a Facebook app it puts up a screen asking for permissions. Does the API enforce this, or is it possible to display a screen using either fake or the user's publicly accessible data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to ask for any permissions right away.  Your app can have the equivalent of a "guest" mode, similar to how many websites work until the user has logged in. I'm not sure why more apps don't operate like that, as a user I'm always a bit put off when something asks for permission before I've even seen the first page of it.

Comment: this is correct.  you won't be able to get any user information until your prompt for permission but you can still show a page. in fact, this is often a much better user experience.